# Plotting fit for binomial lme

Tags: r, data-visualization, binomial-distribution, lme4-nlme, glmm

I've been asked by a reviewer on a manuscript to provide plots of a model fit for a binomial lme which is specified as follows:

```
EVENT_OCCURRED ~ (IV1*IV2) + IV3 + (1|PPT) + (1|RANDOM1) + (1|RANDOM2) + (1|RANDOM3)
```

Where `EVENT_OCCURRED` is a binary value (0/1), `IV1`, `IV2` and `IV3` are independent variables, `PPT` is the participant identifier (it's a behavioral experiment), and `RANDOM1`, `RANDOM2` and `RANDOM3` are random effects.

For the version of the manuscript that I submitted, I included mean-average data that visualised the three IVs and the interaction, without any kind of line fitting the results. Before submitting it, I'd asked a colleague who seemed to think that plotting a model with a bunch of random effects and three independent variables with an interaction wouldn't really make much sense.

However, now I've been asked to do it specifically, I would like to check:

- Is there any way that I could plot the fitted versus actual values for this model?
- Would it involve generating a large number of plots - for example, breaking up the plots and fits by the participant identifier, and for the other random factors?

Comment: I think this question can stay on CV (does not need to be migrated to SO), because I think the larger issue is understanding the ideas behind GLMMs & how they relate to the data visualizations that are possible, rather than this question primarily being about the R code required to get this done.

Comment: Can you add the plot you used in the paper, @elze? Also, it might help people to get some more information, such as N, estimates, & SE's.